# NullPointerException when trying to get data out of intent in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I'm new to Android programming and I have an activity that has an imageButton, when it is clicked, it opens a new activity for results with dialog theme. The user enters some data and clicks submit. I then need to get that data out of the intent to update some images on the first activity. The problem is that I keep getting a NullPointerException when I try to access the string in the intent.

1st activity's onclick method:

```
public void openDetails(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FinalAnalysisDialog.class);
        //add to backStack
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }
```

2nd activity (dialog themed):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.final_analysis_activity);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();  
        //params.x = -100;  
        params.height = 500;  
        params.width = 600;  
        //params.y = -50;  

        this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        //final??
        final Spinner dropDown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.faResultsDropDown);
        dropDown.setSelection(2);

        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.faSubmitButton);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //based on the value of selected item from dropDown (spinner), update the
            //progress status picture
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //dropDown.getSelectedItemPosition();
                String result = dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                //String result = "In process";
                bundle.putString("result", result);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                //intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.putExtra("result", result);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
            }
        });
```

Then I try to get the string back out:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
            //ImageButton mFApic = (ImageButton)home.getView().findViewById(R.id.mInsStepImage);//andrology_home_fragment

            ImageButton mFApic = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mInsStepImage);//andrology_home_fragment
            View mHomeFApic = (View)findViewById(R.id.maleFA);//male_details
            //do something with result
            //Intent dataResult = data.getData();
            //Bundle bundle =dataResult.getExtras();
            //String result = bundle.getString("result");

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            String result = extras.getString("result");
            //String result = data.getStringExtra();
            if (result.equals("Not started")){
                mFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_process);
                mHomeFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_process);
            }else if (result.equals("In process")){
                mFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_process);
                mHomeFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_process);
            }else if (result.equals("Complete")){
                mFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_process);
                mHomeFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_process);
            }else if (result.equals("Problem")){
                mFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_process);
                mHomeFApic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_process);
            }
        }
```

I've tried to send a static string "In process" to see if the problem might be getting value out of spinner but that didn't work. I've searched similar questions but I can't seem to get this to work. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Here's my logCat:

```
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.seattleivf/com.example.seattleivf.TabActionBarHomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3179)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3222)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at com.example.seattleivf.TabActionBarHomeActivity.onActivityResult(TabActionBarHomeActivity.java:197)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5347)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
05-09 14:26:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(4984):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: maybe try intent.putExtra("return-data", true); before you startactivityforresult

Comment: which line is 197 where you are getting the NullPointerException? The stacktrace indicates that the `Intent1 you are returning "has extras", so `data.getExtras()` should not return null. Is it possible that one of your `findViewById()` calls is returning null and you are getting the NPE when using that? Your code looks fine to me. Either add debug logging to see where the problem is or step through it with a debugger.

Comment: You are right, the findViewById() is returning null. What's the trick to accessing a view that's in a fragment from the main activity that's displaying it? I must be missing a basic concept there... Thanks, Sara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You r problem is that you are retrieving the String from the bundle and no the intent itself, try using:

```
String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
```

or simply uncomment the line:

```
//intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and retrieve the String as initially you tried to.

Comment: Ok, I'm able to get result back out but it's crashing when I'm trying to access the view later in my code: 'ImageButton mFApic = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mInsStepImage);//andrology_home_fragment
   View mHomeFApic = (View)findViewById(R.id.maleFA);' How do I access a view that's in a fragment from the activity that's displaying it?